# Business case for higher-kinded types

Tags: higher-kinded-types

Is there a problem for which a language with Higher Kinded Types (HKTs) permits a more concise solution than is possible in any typed language without HKTs?

Comment: Low-hanging-fruit answer is for example they allow to define the Mappable trait, and write functions that will accept any Mappable type, be it List, Vector, Option or user defined. Higher degree of polymorphism and code reuse, much like generics